# Elasticsearch script sorting on nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm using elasticsearch v: 7.10.2. I can not upgrade it.

```js
{
  "properties": {
    "attempts": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "failureReason": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ordinalNumber": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "attemptDate": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

On ui there is a dashboard with columns that allow sorting by `failureReason`

Three columns in general: `firstFailureReason`, `secondFailureReason`, `thirdFailureReason`

I can `understand` which `attempt` object should be considered for sorting by checking its `ordinalNumber` which can be `1 or 2 or 3`

The main problem here is `firstFailureReason` can have two `types` of values:

1. it's an id which has its regular name equivalent in sql, for example 1: Wrong number
2. it can have not id but actual text value, like Wrong number

I implemented similar nested sorting for `attemptDate` field and it works just fine.

But with `failureReason` it's more complicated as values can be `id-based` and I need to map them somehow.

I though about script based sorting. I could pass parameters like

```
{
  1: 'Wrong number',
  2: 'Wrong address',
  ...
}
```

So I thought that I would be able to sort these attempts simply by taking values from map. Using something like this:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "string",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": String reason = doc['failureReason'].value; return params['reason'] ? params['reason'] : reason,
      },
      "order": "asc",
      "nested": {
       "path": "attempts",
       "filter": some filtering here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So basically this script, in my understanding, was supposed to return some text and since I mentioned script type as `string`, it should do string sorting.

However, I faced several issues:

1. I realized that nested filtering does not mean that in script I would be working with attempts only, it seems like I'm still working with top-level documents, thus, that means I need to iterate through attempts of each document....which seems like a bad idea in regards to performance.
2. I do not understand how I can set `missing` attribute value when using script for sorting. I tried to set it on different levels of the sort query, it just does not work. Thus, how can I set the ordering of the documents which have attempts but their failureReasons are `null` ?

Please help me to implement this, I'm struggling here :)

Comment: Why not making sure that `failureReason` has a consistent value at ingest time (maybe using an ingest pipeline)? Whenever you need to resort to scripting it means something's missing in your ingestion process and you should strive to fix it.

Comment: @Val 1. This data has been saved for several years now and it's being done in different variants. My senior colleagues do not want to unify it as they are sure this task is doable via script sorting approach.
2. Saving it as ids means we can change names of reasons anytime, but if we save text values everywhere and tomorrow business team decides to change the name which is a real case, we will need to update millions of documents which we are trying to avoid.

Comment: 1. Just because it's doable via script doesn't mean it's the right approach. Very often it's not and once it's implemented the next question you'll ask is "why is it not performant?" 2. I'm not saying it should be text or number, but that field should have consistent values (whatever they are) to make it usable. The way I see it, ids are the best choice in this case if the textual value can change over time. As you said saving the text value is not ideal since that can change, so you answered that question already.

Comment: @Val, even if we unify the values to one standard and stick with ids, ui dashboard work with text values so we will still need to map those attributes somehow to make sorting on backend. If you are saying it's doable, could you guide me how? I will leave performance aspects up to my colleagues consideration after it's being implemented..